# Count the number of times you can make a given word from the letters of a larger text

Tags: php, string, count, character, find-occurrences

I wanted to make a function which you can see how many times you can make a given word from a text.

For example:

The text is: *Ham followed now ecstatic use speaking exercise may repeated. Himself he evident oh greatly my on inhabit general concern. It allowance prevailed enjoyment in it. Calling observe for who pressed raising his. Can connection instrument astonished unaffected his motionless preference. Announcing say boy precaution unaffected difficulty alteration him.*

```
$text = "Ham followed now ecstatic use speaking exercise may repeated.
Himself he evident oh greatly my on inhabit general concern. It allowance 
prevailed enjoyment in it. Calling observe for who pressed raising his. Can 
connection instrument astonished unaffected his motionless preference. 
Announcing say boy precaution unaffected difficulty alteration him.";

$word = "Potato";
```

I want to know how many times you can write the word "potato". The expected count is `6` times.

I started with something like this:

```
function count($text) {
    for ($i = 0; $i <= strlen($text); $i++) {
        if ($text[$i] == "p") {
            $p = 0;
            $p++;
            echo $p;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you merely trying to count the number of occurrences of each letter in potato?

Comment: i forgot to call the function, but anyways...

Comment: count how many of each letter there are, then use the counts for `p`, `o`, `t`, and `a` to figure out how many potatoes you can make. And don't forget to include `e` if you're a vice president.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you cannot redeclare a `count()` function -- it is already declared as a native function in PHP.

Try this recursive function which contains nested loops:

```
function countt($text, $word, $count = 0) {
    $found = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($word); $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < strlen($text); $j++) {
            if ($word[$i] === $text[$j]) {
                $text = substr($text, 0, $j) . substr($text, $j + 1);
                $found .= $word[$i];
                if ($found === $word) {
                    $count++;
                    return countt($text, $word, $count);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $count;
}

echo countt($text, 'potato');//6
```

Explanation: This recursive function finds occurrences of each letter of a word in text and removes it from the text. Once it completes the new word that is identical to the searched one, it calls this function again with new text, that misses those used letters, until there is no more letters left that could complete another word.

You can play with it here: https://3v4l.org/h43rq

Answer (score 0):

After converting both input strings (assumed to only contain single byte characters) to lowercase, call `count_chars()` on both strings to populate maps of characters and their number of occurrences.

Then loop over the needle's letters and calculate how many times the letter is found and how many times it is used per whole input "word".

Maintain the lowest calculated value as your iterate and break the loop as soon as the value becomes zero.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/rXBFH))

```
$needleCharCounts = count_chars(strtolower($word), 1);
$haystackCharCounts = count_chars(strtolower($text), 1);

$result = null;
foreach ($needleCharCounts as $letter => $count) {
    $result = min($result ?? PHP_INT_MAX, intdiv($haystackCharCounts[$letter] ?? 0, $count));
    if ($result === 0) {
        break;
    }
}
echo $result ?? 0;
// 6
```

Answer (score -1):

this function help you to get how many times `paroto` has used in that string

```
echo substr_count($text, $word);
```

Comment: Care to comment on what this does? Posting a block of code isn't terribly helpful.

Comment: no sorry, I'm trying to make a function on my own, not with a already excisted function. But thanks for replying

Comment: Machavity, the code doesn't work, so it doesn't show anything good unfortunately

Answer (score -1):

My approach would be to go through the text storing each character in a dictionary where the key is the letter and the value is the number of occurrences in the text. Once you finish processing the text you can calculate how many times you can spell potato

Comment: This hint could have been a comment under the question.